# Check for specific string within wget result set and update the log based on that

Tags: string, search, wget

I have a permanently VPN connection to a server in Germany. I have intermittent outages of this connection where the VPN connection drops and it falls back to default broadband ISP based internet connection path. I am trying to track this outages by using the way google works depending where your connection originating from. If I connect from my default connection in US, I get the standard google.com server, but if I connect over the VPN server in germany google.com connection attempt resolves to google.de site instead of google.com. This is a suitable criteria to see if connection is down.

So, if I issue a wget against "www.google.com" the resulting set will include either google.de in indicating that google detects that the connection is from germany or google.com which will indicate the connection is coming from U.S which means for my purposes that the VPN connection is down. I can't figure out the proper syntax for the wget and the grep to follow to make this specific determination in the script.

The script I came up with doesn't seem to work consistently. When it is executed by cru (cron) it gets US when I execute interactively I get Germany.
Any suggestions?

rm index*

wget -nv google.com 2 > /jffs/user/google.txt

cat google.txt | grep google.de

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then

echo "$(date) Germany" >> /jffs/user/google.log

else

echo "$(date) U.S." >> /jffs/user/google.log

fi

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: What is Cru? [too short]

Comment: cru is same as the cron utility